# How to Properly setup Scala in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: windows, scala, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to setup Scala on Jupyter Notebook and I have been following this Github page to do the setup https://github.com/vericast/spylon-kernel

But when I used the spylon kernel in Jupyter Notebook. After executing the cell, it just frozen with this message `Intitializing Scala interpreter ...`. I waited for an hour and it still wont show anything other than that message.

I tried to look for solutions on Stackoverflow and Github but still couldnt solve this issue. I am wondering does anyone here know how to solve it? Or have any other alternatives for me to use Scala on Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 1):

`spylon-kernel` hasn't been updated in several years and it does not work properly these days. Instead, its much better to use [almond](https://almond.sh/) - "A Scala kernel for Jupyter".

Answer (score 0):

Check the command prompt of jupyter note-book and see if there is any error.
normally this happens when there is mismatch between spark version and python in anaconda